# Why the `count` query results for a single table in Apache IoTDB cannot came back?

Tags: count, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Why the result of `count` command in Apache IoTDB cannot came back? I am now using Version 0.13 of IoTDB, and I need to query data in a single table. The size of data in the table is about 200 million. I added `Time` as `where` condition, and the `count` result did not return when `Time` is set to one hour, half an hour, or 10 minutes. The whole sql statement is `Select count(station_id) from root.fz4 .pv.s_5.** where Time >= 2023-08-31 07:00:00.000000 AND Time <= 2023-08-31 07:10:00.000000 group by level=1`. I want to know why this query is slow?

Answer (score 0):

The speed of `count` query in Apache IoTDB has nothing to do with the time range set to the sql statement. When you are doing this kind of query across different devices, all time series needs to be queried out first Therefore, if you have a large amount of data stored, the efficiency may be affected.